# How to build binary tree knowing only which nodes are connected?

Tags: algorithm, graph, binary-tree

I have to build a binary tree but i don't know which node is parent, left child, or right child. I only know which nodes are connected. Example: for input like this:

```
6 4
5 7
9 7
1 5
10 4
3 4
2 6
7 8
5 6
```

(from 1 there is always one path) the tree should looks like that:
[image]

One the input i have also given number of nodes. Any ideas, tips?

Comment: Do a breadth-first search starting at 1

Comment: So you will build [isomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism) graphs depending on which child you take first.

Answer (score 1):

From the list of the edges, one can easily create a tree.

You can find which are the leaf nodes, just search which nodes are appearing only in one edge.
But, it is not possible to know which of the leaf nodes is the head of the tree.
In a tree structure it is possible to choose any leaf, choose it as the head, and reorder the tree, and it'll be a valid tree.

There is also the issue of **tree isomorphism**, you can swap the right and left sub-trees to get a valid tree.

To summarize, from this list you can get 6 heads and in each 4 possible swaps, so in total 24 different valid trees.